# Fortify Tool Buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, secure-coding

```
char tmp[] = "hello world";
char *line;
size_t sz;

sz = strlen(tmp) +1;
line = (char*)malloc(sz);

if (line)
    memset(line, 0x00, sz);
```

Using a tool called Fortify, it flags the memset as a Buffer Overflow. Any one know why?

Comment: Give the exact and complete error. Maybe it's complaining because the code does not check for `malloc` failure.

Comment: The `memset` call seems fine, but `malloc()`'s return value should be checked, as kaylum said. Also, you probably wanted to allocate `sz + 1` bytes unless you want unexpected behavior (remember that C strings are NUL-terminated) or unless `line` will be shorter than `tmp`. P.S.: casting `malloc()` to `char*` (or whatever specific pointer type) is discouraged.

Comment: There is no error. Fortify is a tool to alert you of security flaws in you code. A potential for someone to exploit your code. The exploit here is buffer overflow.

Comment: I mean, show the full message from fortify.

Comment: Try `sz = strlen(tmp) + 1` and tell us if the message goes away

Comment: @AdamJones The reason why Fortify is telling you that there is a buffer overflow is probably caused by: 1) you don't check for `malloc()`'s return value (this is a security hole); 2) Fortify recognizes the pattern `line = malloc(strlen(tmp))` as this is a security hole in many programs (not the intended behavior wanted by the programmer), *but* it is not a problem if you *actually intended* the variable `line` to hold fewer chars than `tmp` (rarely the case). I never used Fortify but I suppose this could help.

Comment: +1 on strlen did not work nor adding a check on malloc. The buffer Overflow warning still exist. Fortify says "might be able to write outside the bounds of allocated memory on line 9, which could corrupt data cause the program to crash or lead to the execution of malicious code."

Comment: If after your second edit, Fortify is still issuing warnings, then I wonder how many errors Fortify would issue if it read its own source code.